# Mongodb find different values from arrays

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDb version 5.0.6.

I have this structure:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("60c7180d5ef87b4de490c56d"),
  "data": {
    "user": [
      {"country": "Netherlands", "originalCountry": "Denmark"},
      {"country": "France", "originalCountry": "Denmark"},
    ]
  },
"_id": ObjectId("60c7180d5ef87b4de490c56d"),
  "data": {
    "user": [
      {"country": "ITALIE", "originalCountry": "ITALIE"},
      {"country": "France", "originalCountry": "France"},
    ]
  }
},
"_id": ObjectId("60c7180d5ef87b4de490c56d"),
  "data": {
    "user": [
      {"country": "UK", "originalCountry": "CANADA"},
      {"country": "France", "originalCountry": "France"},
    ]
  }
}
```

I wish to find only the documents that have `country` equal to `supplierCountry`in this case:

```
"_id": ObjectId("60c7180d5ef87b4de490c56d"),
  "data": {
    "user": [
      {"country": "ITALIE", "originalCountry": "ITALIE"},
      {"country": "France", "originalCountry": "France"},
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried with this query

```
db.collection.find({
  "data.user": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "country": {
        $ne: "$data.user.originalCountry"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

but the result is not right.

Comment: There are multiple issues with your sample documents. 1. Is the correct field name `supplierCountry` or `originalCountry`? 2. Some of the documents seem broken. We don't know if they are separate documents or embedded documents. 3. duplicate `_id` Other than the issues, is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kkPFKx7Mn0h) what you are looking for?

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/NgWGWzIdh8-

Comment: I have fix the example. It is a simple example but I have this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `$map`, you can project the `data.user` array to an array of boolean by comparing the 2 country fields. Then, use `$allElementsTrue` to find documents that have all array entries true. (i.e. all array entries are having  same country)

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$allElementsTrue": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$data.user",
        "as": "u",
        "in": {
          $eq: [
            "$$u.country",
            "$$u.originalCountry"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e9Km2cRoUj0)

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregation. This will compare the 2 values `country` and `originalCountry` in the same `user` object array and return those documents

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          "$data.user.country",
          "$data.user.originalCountry"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Mongo Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/OhJXK7CC3HX